# how to remove synaptic button error

Tags: 19.10

using Ubuntu 19.10 since few days (after 25 years of windows). Have installed Synaptic button for quick access to Synaptic Package Manager. Button appeared on taskbar, but does not work, says "Error". Any way to remove it, complete uninstall? I cannot trace it in Package Manager. Sorry if it`s a stupid question...
thank you!

Comment: From where or how did you install "Synaptic button"?

Comment: ashamed to say I can`t remember, nor find on the web the location... some tutorial, might have been old, as I recall referred to older distro of Ubuntu... in windows I shld hv been able to find and clean up everything fm hdd, registry... sorry